# Remove specific tags when displaying data from database in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I've got some data that I need to display in a GridView and then enable the user to export it as an excel file. 
The sql currently looks like this:

```
public static class Export
{
    public static DataTable ExportData()
    {

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["product.products_tblConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TITLE, CUSTOMER, PRODUCTS, PHOTOGRAPHS FROM products_tbl WHERE LANG = 'EN' ", conn))
        {
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(data);
            return data;

        }

    }
}
```

Now the problem is: In the database there are several things like `<p>` tags or `<br>` and extra spaces etc. I can't get rid of them in the database, but I do need to get rid of them either when getting the data from the db and before displaying it in the `GridView` **or** once that data is exported to an excel file by the user.

My export to excel function looks like this :

```
 private void ExportGridToExcel()
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.Charset = "";
    string FileName = "Product" + DateTime.Now + ".xls";
    StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
    Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    ResultsFilter();
    GridView1.DataBind();
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
    GridView1.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
    GridView1.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
    GridView1.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
    Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
    Response.End();

}
```

Before I just used the Sql Server Data export manager and used replace to get rid of the extra tags etc. so something like this :

```
SELECT  
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE("CUSTOMER",'<p>',''),'</p>',''),'<br>','')
 ,'</br>',''),'  ','') ,'   ',''),'\n','')  as 'CUSTOMER',

 FROM dbo.products_tbl

FROM
```

I know it's not pretty, but it worked. I tried to use the same kind of thing in the sql query in my .cs file but it doesn't seem to remove the tags, spaces etc. 
Anybody know how I can achieve this either when getting the data from the database or when the user exports it to excel?

Comment: I wouldn't do it in the sql level at all. instead, use a regular expression that will allow you to replace everything you want in a single replace in c#.

Comment: Agreed keep your business logic out of your data access, better yet, why not "sanitize" it when inserting?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Do you happen to have any resource or examples on how to do it with reg ex? don't know much about it

Comment: Since you are working with c#, [Here is one from msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx), and [here is the Regex.Replace Method documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)